# How to replace/delete all BUT the first character in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello community: I have a quick question as I am still familiarizing myself with regex. My Question is: How do i replace/delete all BUT the first character in a string in JavaScript?

Sample: If my string is "apple" and I would only want "a".

Answer (score 11):

You don't need regular expressions to remove all but the first character(s) in a string.

Use the [`.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
'apple'.slice(0, 1);
// 'a'
```

You can also just access the first character using the `.charAt()` method:

```
'apple'.charAt(0);
// 'a'
```

---

If you want to use the `.replace()` method, then you could use the following:

```
'apple'.replace(/(^.).*/, '$1');
// 'a'
```

- In regular expressions, the `.` character matches *any* character.
- `(^.)` is a capture group that will capture the first character
- `.*` will match all the following characters (`*` means any character will be matched zero or more times).
- Then we are essentially replacing everything with the first capture group, `'$1'`.